# VBA run time error 1004 in VBA, application defined or object definned error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the error raised above on a piece of code I reuse very regularly. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. The error is occur at this line:

```
ws4.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(D2="", E2, D2)"
```

Then LastRow variable is working and ws4 is defined. I am lost.

Thanks

Comment: Worksheet is locked or protected?

Comment: Shouldn't your `D2=""` be `D2=""""`? Also, what is `ws4` exactly? It needs to be a Worksheet object.

Comment: Are you able to write this to a *single* cell, e.g., `ws4.Range("F2").Formula = "=IF(D2="""",E2,D2)"`?

Comment: @HaoZhang presumably it is a worksheet object, and it is assigned properly, otherwise a 424 error or 91 error, respectively.

Comment: If it only happens sometimes, then I'd reckon your `LastRow` might be going out of bound.

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for your replies, David:I cannot write it to a single cell I get the same error. Hao, thank you very much the double quotes solved it.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in an empty Excel sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim rngCell     As Range

    lastRow = 5

    For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
        rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(1=1,2,3)"
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Then try to see the differences between it and your code. It can be that you are  not referring to the correct sheet or something else. The sheet can be locked as well (e.g. `1004` is for this as well). Or some cells can be locked. Thus, the looping can help you.